# how to check for a variable in select drop-down if one of the option is 0

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a drop-down option in my php form ...

```
    <div class="field">
      <label>* Number of People</label>
      <select class="ui dropdown" name="male">
        <option value="">Gender Male</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 0 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="0">0</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
        <option <?php if ($male == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
      </select>
      <?php if(isset($maleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $maleErr . '</span>'); ?>
    </div>
```

However, since the first option is 0, the original error-checking which is this:

```
   if (empty($_POST["male"])) {
     $maleErr = "# of people (gender male) required";
   } else {
     $male = test_input($_POST["male"]);
   }
```

kept popping up with the error that it hadn't been set. I realized that since 0 equals empty for php's empty function, I changed it to this:

```
   if (is_null($_POST["male"])) {
     $maleErr = "# of people (gender male) required";
   } else {
     $male = test_input($_POST["male"]);
   }
```

Is that the correct way to check for a form's field not to be empty?

Please let me know. Thank you.

**Addendum**

Do you mean like this?

```
  <option <?php if ($male === 0 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="0">0</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never be null so can't use `is_null()`.  It will always be set so can't use `isset()`.  And as you've seen `0` is empty.  So to check that an option has been selected try checking that it's not an empty string:

```
if ($_POST["male"] === "") {
    $maleErr = "# of people (gender male) required";
} else {
    $male = test_input($_POST["male"]);
}
```

Comment: which will STILL fail, because `0 == ""` is true.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, thanks for your solution. Using it. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

use the [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
if ($male === 0)
```

`===` compares value AND type, so while `0 == ''` is true, `0 === ''` is false.

Comment: hey, please look at my addendum in my post above. Did you mean it like that? I just tried it on my form, and I still get the error triggered, ie this: ` * # of people (gender male) required `

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765: No, I think Marc is looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: guess so, but the solution is the same. `if (isset($_POST['male']) && ($_POST['male'] === ""))  { ... gender missing ....}`. can't do `== ""` or `== 0`, because `==` will give a false positive.

Comment: @MarcB, hey, thanks for taking the time to respond. Appreciate it.